# Rank the education levels

Tags: degree, education

I am working with data on "parental level of education". I have ranked the following levels from the lowest to the highest. I am a foreigner and I do not understand the US education system. Could you please validate?

1. some high school
2. high school
3. associate's degree
4. bachelor's degree
5. some college
6. master's degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume if your highest attainment is "some college", that means you attended college, but did not obtain a qualification. Therefore this should rank at #3: you have done something after completing high school, but not enough to get any of the degrees. (Similarly, "some high school" is below "[completed] high school", which you have in the right place.)

An associate degree is, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_degree)

> a level of qualification above a high school diploma, GED, or matriculation, and below a bachelor's degree.

Here "matriculation" means the process of entering university/college, so it is equivalent to your "some college". Thus associate degree is #4, and bachelors degree #5. (Associate degree is an unusual one, since it is the only entry in the list which is not a usual prerequisite to the next one.)

As EarlGrey mentions in the comment, there should be a #7 for doctoral and other degrees which are higher than masters.

Comment: @pigeon_gcc I don't think it's possible to rank associate's/some college. An associate's is typically two years and a bachelor's four. But someone who dropped out of a bachelor's might have dropped out at three years and reported "some college." Having worked with the same type of data, I would probably collapse those categories (they are probably fairly small).

Comment: It might be they are working with the actual responses, in which case there might not be anyone with a qualification beyond a master's.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I would regard three years of college without a qualification as less impressive than two years with a qualification, but YMMV. I agree that it would make sense to combine those two categories, though - I have never previously seen associate degree as a separate category in this sort of context.

Comment: Well, it's "years of education" not "how impressive of an education."

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I see no mention of "years" in OP. It is "level of education", and I consider getting an associate degree constitutes a higher level than getting no degree, no matter how long either of these took.

Comment: Okay, well, it's usually "years."

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- If it's years of education, that is just a number and I see no reason to introduce categories at all.

Comment: It would be nice if they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have levels 3, 4, and 5 disordered. An associates degree implies (usually) two years of college. A bachelors comes at the end of (usually) four years of college. And, you do need "doctoral degree" after masters. High school (2) should probably be "high school diploma", which implies successful completion of high school.

It is rare, but there are also people with no high school at all.

Comment: *there are also people with no high school at all.* --- No high school is now quite rare. Moreover, after several minutes of searching I have not found an estimated percentage, but it's probably less than 1%. On the other hand, about 10% of the U.S. population does NOT have a high school diploma, which is roughly the same percentage as all those (combined) who do have a graduate degree (Masters or Ph.D.) or a professional degree, as well as about 1/5 of those having a Ph.D. degree (about 2%). See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_attainment_in_the_United_States).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro In one dataset I have of about 2000 answers I believe people who endorsed "less than high school" is less than 5. It might be 1. These are numbers I haven't looked at in a while. I would believe the true rate is 0.1% or so.